# Can a morphism to affine scheme be factored through the canonical morphism?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm reading Gortz's Algebraic Geometry, p.84, Theorem 3.42, saying that every closed subscheme of  an affine scheme is also affine.

First, I propose an associated question.

Let $(i,i^{\flat}):Z \to X =\operatorname{Spec}A$ be a morphism of schemes (can be a closed immersion).

Let $\varphi := i^{\flat}_X : A \to \Gamma(Z,\mathcal{O}_Z)$ be the induced morphism.

Let $c_{Z} : Z \to \operatorname{Spec}\Gamma(Z,\mathcal{O}_Z)$ be the canonical morphism induced by next bijection (his book Proposition 3.4)

$$ \operatorname{Hom}(Z,\operatorname{Spec}\Gamma(Z,\mathcal{O}_Z))\cong \operatorname{Hom}
(\Gamma(Z,\mathcal{O}_Z), \Gamma(Z,\mathcal{O}_Z))
$$

Question : Then $i =\operatorname{Spec}(\varphi) \circ c_Z$ ? If not, when?

This question originates from next proof of the Theorem 3.42 in Gortz's book :

[image]

Why the inclusion $i:Z\to X$ factors through $Z \to \operatorname{Spec}A/I_Z$?

Since we do not prove that $Z$ is affine until now, we can't let $Z \cong \operatorname{Spec}\Gamma(Z,\mathcal{O}_Z)$. But neverthelss, if our question is true, then $i$ factors through $Z \to \operatorname{Spec}A/I_Z$ by simple argument.

Is the question true? Or.. perhaps he made somewhat mistake? In Liu's Algebraic Geometry book, he  proves by different method. Anyway, I want to make sure whether Gortz's method works.

Can anyone helps?

Comment: I think the answer to your question is true in general (?) Your equation between those morphisms of schemes can be checked locally on the source, and if you restrict to any affine open in $Z$ you should get that the equality holds trivially (since $c_Z$ restricts to the identity).

Comment: Thanks, helpful comment. It's like that I finally prove the statement. (In particular, it was helpful that we can check the equality on some affine opens.)